# nhibernate mapping many-to-many: why was the whole bag collections deleted and reinserted?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, bidirectional-relation

Nhibernate users, professionals, gurus and developers are expected. Please help !!!

I want to realise a n:m relation between two classes. A student attends in more courses and a course consists of more students as members. I do a bidirectional association many-to-many with bag to get the both lists from each site.

The two Student and Course classes:

```
public class Student {         
     // Attributes........

     [XmlIgnore]
     public virtual IList MyCourses { get; set; }

     // Add Method
     public virtual void AddCourse(Course c)
    {
        if (MyCourses == null)
            MyCourses = new List<Course>();

        if (!MyCourses.Contains(c))
            MyCourses.Add(c);

        if (c.Members== null)
            c.Members= new List<Student>();

        if (!c.Members.Contains(this))
            c.Members.Add(this);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveCourse(Course c)
    {
        if (MyCourses != null)
            MyCourses.Remove(c);

        if (c.Members!= null)
            c.Members.Remove(this);
    }
}

public class Course {         
     // Attributes........

     [XmlIgnore]
     public virtual IList Members { get; set; }
}
```

In database there are two tables t_Student, t_Course and a relation table tr_StudentCourse(id, student_id, course_id).

```
<class name="Student" table="t_Student" polymorphism="explicit">
 ..... 
 <bag name="MyCourses" table="tr_StudentCourse">
   <key column="student_id" />
   <many-to-many class="Course" column="course_id" not-found="ignore" />
 </bag>    
</class>

<class name="Course" table="t_Course" polymorphism="explicit">
 ..... 
 <bag name="Members" table="tr_StudentCourse" inverse="true">
   <key column="course_id" />
   <many-to-many class="Student" column="student_id" not-found="ignore" />
 </bag>    
</class>
```

Course was chosen as *inverse* in the bidirectional association. I did the same as example (Categorie, Item) in section 6.8 of nhibernate documentation. So I saved the student object after inserting a course in the list MyCourses by calling the Add/Remove-method.

```
Student st1 = new Student();
Course c1 = new Course();    
Course c2 = new Course();
st1.AddCourse(c1);
st1.AddCourse(c2);
session.saveOrUpdate(st1);
```

That works fine, the st1, c1 and their relation (st1,c1) can be find in the database. The relation datasets are (id=**1**, st1.id, c1.id) and (id=**2**, st1.id, c2.id).
Then I add more courses to the object st1.

```
Course c3 = new Course();
st1.AddCourse(c3);
session.saveOrUpdate(st1);
```

I can see the 3 relation datasets, but the two old relations were deleted and new three were created with another new id. (id=**3**, st1.id, c1.id), (id=**4**, st1.id, c2.id) and (id=**5**, st1.id, c3.id). There are not dataset with id=1 and 2 more in relation table.

The same by deleting if I remove a course from student.MyCourse and then save the student object. All collection was also deleted and recreated a new list which less one deleted element. That problem makes the id in the relation table increates very fast and a have troble by doing a backup of relation.

I have looked some days in internet, documentation and forums to find out why the whole old collection was deleted and a new as created by each changing, but I was not successful. It is a bug from nhibernate mapping or did I do any wrong?

I am very very grateful to your help and answer.

Nhibernate documentation http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

> NHibernate can't create, delete or
>   update rows individually, because
>   there is no key that may be used to
>   identify an individual row.

By [note from "6.2. Mapping a Collection"](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/collections.html)

As soon as you have `id` in `tr_StudentCourse` you can try using indexed collections, i.e. replace `<bag>` with `<map>` or similar and add `<index>` element to the mapping:

```
<index
    column="id"
    type="int"
/>
```

or even create a special entity for the relation table to use with `<index-many-to-many>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've found on the NHibernate website:

> Hibernate is deleting my entire
>   collection and recreating it instead
>   of updating the table.
>
> This generally happens when NHibernate
>   can't figure out which items changed
>   in the collection. Common causes are:
>
> - replacing a persistent collection
>     entirely with a new collection
>     instance passing NHibernate a manually
>     constructed object and calling Update
>     on it.
> - serializing/deserializing a
>     persistent collection apparently also
>     causes this problem.
>
>   - updating a 
>       with inverse="false" - in this case,
>       NHibernate can't construct SQL to
>       update an individual collection item.
>
> Thus, to avoid the problem:
>
> pass the same collection instance that
>   you got from NHibernate back to it
>   (not necessarily in the same session),
>   try using some other collection
>   instead of `<bag>` (`<idbag>` or `<set>`),
>   or try using inverse="true" attribute
>   for `<bag>`.